# Как во Vue.js сохранить данные из input в localstorage и вывести их оборатно в инпут

Tags: javascript, vue.js, framework7

Как во Vue.js сохранить данные из input в localstorage и вывести их оборатно в инпут.

Пробовал делать по примеру с оффсайта vue.js , но мне нужно использовать framewwork7, а там  v-model не поддерживается.

А так постоянно в инпуте выводит [object InputEvent]. Если перезагрузить страницу или убрать курсор синпута тоже самое, всегда [object InputEvent].
В консоли при попытке ввода выдаёт. ---> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: $event is not defined" found in --->       at src/pages/login.vue    at src/app.vue  vue.esm.js:629:7

```
  <f7-list form>
    <f7-list-input
      label="Username"
      name="username"
      placeholder="Username"
      type="text"
      v-bind:value="name"
      required validate
      pattern="[3-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+"
      @input="persist"
    />
  </f7-list>

<script>
export default {
data() {
    return{
        name: '',
        }
    },
mounted() {
  if (localStorage.name) {
    this.name = localStorage.getItem('name')
  }
}, 

 methods: {
             persist(){
                localStorage.setItem('name', $event.target.value)
        }
    }
    };
    </script>
[![Вот что выводи
```

т в инпуте][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h0Od.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h0Od.jpg)

Comment: Попробуй в функцию persist добавить this.name = event.target.value и event указать в принимаемых аргументах

Comment: persist(event){
    this.name = event.target.value;
    localStorage.setItem('name', event.target.value);
}

Comment: Господи я две недели над этим мучился. Спасибо огромное.

Comment: А подскажи пожалуйста, что означает вот это условие  -->               if(localStorage.name)

Comment: Это проверка существования ключа name в localStorage